# how to save edittext value in a listview to android sqlite?

Tags: android, listview

Quiz activity

[image]

how can i get all the value of the edit text in the list view and save it to sqlite DB? i already did some research on google for this but no luck, i really don't have any idea, can anyone give me a sample, any help will be very much appreciated, thank you so much

this is my code for inserting quiz results:

```
  /**
     * Insert into Quiz
     * @param students
     * @param date_time
     * @param quizresult
     * @return
     */

public boolean insert_quiz(ArrayList<Student> students, String date_time, String quizresult){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        int numberOfSuccessfulInsert = 0;
    for (Student student : students ) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("date_time", date_time);
        values.put("quizzes", quizresult);
        values.put("classroomstudent_id", student.getClassroomStudentId());
        boolean isSuccessful = db.insert("quiz", null, values)>0;

        if (isSuccessful)
            numberOfSuccessfulInsert++;
    }

    db.close();

    //kung ok, send tru
    if (students.size() == numberOfSuccessfulInsert)
        return true;
    else //kung not ok, send false
        return false;
```

Comment: Well, you should take one tutorial at the time, first, working with Listview, then how to iterate on the Custom listview to get each value. Then how to insert a Bean (lineId, Score) into a SQlite Db. But this is not really the place for this.

Answer (score 1):

Use this Link for Custom ListViews tutorial [Custom ListView tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

And this for SQLite tutorial
[SQLite tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to traverse the listview childs and then you will get each row edittext value . Below is the code.

```
for(int i=0; i< lstView.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
    View wantedView = listView.getChildAt(0);
    Edittext edittext = (Edittext) findViewById(R.id.edtid);
    // get edittext value
     String value = edittext.getText().toString();
}
```